# Permissions changes on Windows event log are not working (GPO change)

Tags: permissions, windows-event-log, windows-registry

I'm trying to grant permissions to the Network Service account (SID S-1-5-20) on the event log **"Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational"** (see picture below). However I need to push this change on more than 1000 servers, and more are coming. So my solution has to be linked somehow to a GPO (I trying to avoid the usage of a script with the GPO for technical reasons).

[image: CAPI2 event log]

According the [instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc722385(v=ws.10))  from  Microsoft, you have to:

1. Create a new registry key named "CustomSD" under the concerned event log key in '*HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\custom_log*'
2. Create a string "CustomSD" with the proper permissions defined in the SSDL
   format:  *O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x2;;;AU)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-20)*
3. Restart the host and verify permissions

However, when I reboot the host and I check the permissions using the following commands, I can see that the new permissions are not applied:

```
wevtutil get-log "Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational"  OR
Get-WinEvent -ListLog "Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational"  | Format-List -Property *
```

[image: SDDL permissions]

Where I am confused is that only the following keys related to the main event logs are available in : '*HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\'*

[image: Registry log]

And in my case I have tried to :

- create a new registry key in '*HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\CAPI2*" >> did not work

[image]

- create the registry key in the following path
  *'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\application\Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2'* since the name of the event log was present >> did not work
  [image: Custom SD on CAPI]

> So my point is that I do not understand why the permissions are not updated. Am I doing something wrong ? I have also checked the following [link](https://blog.backslasher.net/event-log-permissions-with-scripts.html) but it seeems that it applies only on the event log available in '*HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the great answer from @GregAskew, I was able to push event log permissions over GPO. My steps were:

1. Create a new GPO and browse to the Registry settings (available in Computer > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry) to update the "ChannelAccess" entry
   [image: gpo registry]
2. Add the proper permissions in the SDDL format in the field Value data:
   [image: Value data]
3. Enable the event log CAPI2 (deactivated per default) updating the registry key "Enabled" to 1
   [image: enabled]
4. As a result my GPO looks like that:
   [image: GPO result]

> After the GPO is activated and applied, you can check on your target
>   client the correct application of the permissions by browsing to the
>   following path in the registry

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\<event log>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use wevtutil to set the permissions:

```
wevtutil set-log "Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational" /channelaccess:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x2;;;AU)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-20)

wevtutil get-log "Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational"

name: Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational
enabled: false
type: Operational
owningPublisher: Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2
isolation: Application
channelAccess: O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x2;;;AU)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-20)
logging:
  logFileName: %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2%4Operational.evtx
  retention: false
  autoBackup: false
  maxSize: 1052672
publishing:
  fileMax: 1
```

Comment: Hi Greg, thansk for the answer. However I did not mention that I need to have this solution builtin into a GPO. Of course I could use a script that execute your command, but for technical constraint, I trying to avoid a script method. Pushing registry keys over per GPO would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Then you should create a registry preference for Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational Value: ChannelAccess

Comment: Thanks Greg, this works for me with the new registry key path. Can I suggest you to post your last comment as an answer, so I can validate it ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @MicheldeCrevoisier: sure thing, done.